# How to use an annotation to replace code in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, lombok

I want to be able to process a java project pre-build so I can locate all annotations, such as @Getter, and replace them with an actual getter statement for the assigned field.

```
@Getter String s = "string";
```

I basically want to do what "Project Lombok" does, but I want to do it myself, to learn as well as simplify it for my needs.

The problem is, well, I don't know where to start. I have searched and have found nothing of any use, and have tried myself as well, with no luck. I would like it to run on eclipse build, so the jar is automatically correct. I also would like to create it so when I insert the annotation into a java file it doesn't show as an error, which I assume I can fix this with a dependency.

As far as experience goes, I know how to use and create annotations, but only for storing meta-data, and not being used as a placeholder, per-say.

If you have any tips or know of any resources to help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

P.S. I already looked through Project Lombok's source code, and it was too extensive to locate what needs to be done.

Comment: This Wikipedia article about Java annotations should be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation

Comment: Puce's answer is right. Annotation processors are supposed to write a new file, not to modify an existing class. What Lombok does is pretty complicated and hard to understand, but only because there's no simple way.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Lombok does some AST manipulation in annotation processors (not 100% sure), which isn't officially supported by the specification. Thus it's more like a hack to overcome some shortcomings in the Java language.

Comment: That is 100% correct (for javac, Eclipse is a different story). Using annotation processors it is officially not possible to modify existing code. Full Disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok core developers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a custom annotation processor.

Basically you'll be searching for your annotations and adding custom code to the resulting class file before the the final compilation step.

Your processor needs to implement `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` to handle your annotations. I've done this before for NetBeans and used a good article from a few years ago as a guide http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. First of all you need to attach lombok.jar to your project.
Right click your project & go to properties. Attach external jar/library. Now import the following:-

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
// and so on....
```

Now you're able to use @Getter @Setter as follows:-

```
@Getter @Setter private Car car;
```

Now you're able to use getCar() & setCar(...)
Note:- You may need to enable annotation processing for NetBeans. Don't ask me how to do that. Just google it or visit lombok's site.

Comment: If you read my question you would see I was asking how to do this on my own, and used lombok as an example, rather than wanted to know how to use it...